# execvpe on Windows not returning ExitValue

Tags: python, windows, exec

I'm using [`execvpe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=execv#os.execvpe) to execute a program replacing the current process.

This works well on all platforms (Linux, Windows, Mac), the only thing that seems different is that the `ExitValue` of the called program is not returned correctly on Windows.

For context: The program is called [`dotenv`](https://github.com/venthur/dotenv-cli) and it reads `.env` files adds them to the environment variables and executes the program using the new environment. Naturally the program's `ExitValue` must be returned by `dotenv` as well.

I have a simple test that works for Linux and Mac but is failing on Windows:

```py
def test_returncode(dotenvfile: Path) -> None:
    proc = subprocess.run(['dotenv', 'false'])
    assert proc.returncode == 1

    proc = subprocess.run(['dotenv', 'true'])
    assert proc.returncode == 0
```

Is there a way to make `execvpe` return the exit value or do I have to check for `os.name == 'posix'` and use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20popen#subprocess.Popen) for Windows?

Comment: What is `run` here?

Comment: @MichaelButscher good catch! It is subprocess.run, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: `execvpe` is neither used by the shown code nor by `dotenv`. Where is it?

Comment: it is os.execvpe -- there's a link to the python docs in the question. in dotenv itself, it is currently in two pull requests, as i'm evaluating the usage of execvpe over Popen.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101191